# Change/remove predefined title from bibliography section

Tags: bibliographies, koma-script

I am using the scrartcl document type for my CV and I want to add my publications as bibliography section. However, I already have a title for the section from the CV template, and when I include the following code an extra title appears named "Publications" and with totally different fonts that I already have in the CV

```
\begingroup
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\begin{thebibliography}
\footnotesize{
\bibitem \newblock bla bla bla
\bibitem \newblock bla bla bla
}
\end{thebibliography}
\endgroup
```

Have tried commands like

```
\renewcommand{\bibtitle}{}
\renewcommand{\bibheadtitle}{}

\renewcommand{\refname}{} 
\renewcommand\refname{}
```

and none of them work in order to modify at least the title even though I do not wish a title since I have the customised one from the CV template.
Any ideas or suggestions?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\renewcommand*\refname{}
\reversemarginpar
\newcommand{\MarginText}[1]{\marginpar{\raggedleft\itshape\small#1}} 
\usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis} 
\usepackage[LabelsAligned]{currvita}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\renewcommand{\cvheadingfont}{\LARGE\color{Cyan}} 
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand*\refname{}}
\renewcommand*\refname{}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks, breaklinks, urlcolor=Maroon, linkcolor=Maroon} 
\newlength{\datebox}\settowidth{\datebox}{January Jul2011}
\newcommand{\NewEntry}[3]{\noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0 \parbox{\datebox}{\small \textit{#1}}\hspace{0.5em} #2 #3 
\vspace{0.5em}}

\newcommand{\Description}[1]{\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0\noindent\footnotesize{#1}\par\normalsize\vspace{1em}} 
\date{}

\begin{document}


\begin{cv}{\spacedallcaps{Bla}}\vspace{1.5em} % Your name

\noindent\spacedlowsmallcaps{Personal Information}\vspace{0.5em} % Personal information heading

%------------------------------
%   PUBLICATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\noindent\spacedlowsmallcaps{Publications}\vspace{1em}


\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\bib@heading{}

\begingroup
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\begin{thebibliography}{2}
\footnotesize{
\begin{footnotesize}
\bibitem{a}
Bla bla


\bibitem{b}
Bla bla

\end{footnotesize}
}
\end{thebibliography}


\endgroup
\makeatother

\end{cv}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make a minimal example: the solution will most probably depend on the class and packages you're loading.

Comment: @egreg Just added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loading `natbib` is irrelevant, because `currvita` changes the code for `thebibliography`.

Also resetting `\refname` or `\bib@heading` does nothing.

The trick is to patch the `cv` example so that the `thebibliography` environment doesn't print a header.

I reordered your document preamble: first the packages, then the settings. I also added a better way to set the bibliography in `\footnotesize`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis} 

\usepackage[LabelsAligned]{currvita}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{colorlinks, breaklinks, urlcolor=Maroon, linkcolor=Maroon} 

\reversemarginpar

\patchcmd{\cv}{\noindent\cvlistheadingfont\cvbibname\par\nopagebreak}{}{}{}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{thebibliography}{\begingroup\footnotesize}
\AfterEndEnvironment{thebibliography}{\endgroup}

\renewcommand{\cvheadingfont}{\LARGE\color{Cyan}} 
\newcommand{\MarginText}[1]{\marginpar{\raggedleft\itshape\small#1}} 
\newlength{\datebox}
\settowidth{\datebox}{January Jul2011}
\newcommand{\NewEntry}[3]{%
  \noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0 
  \parbox{\datebox}{\small \textit{#1}}\hspace{0.5em} #2 #3 \vspace{0.5em}%
}

\newcommand{\Description}[1]{%
  \hangindent=2em\hangafter=0
  \noindent\footnotesize{#1}\par\normalsize\vspace{1em}%
} 

\date{}

\begin{document}


\begin{cv}{\spacedallcaps{Bla}}\vspace{1.5em} % Your name

\noindent\spacedlowsmallcaps{Personal Information}\vspace{0.5em} % Personal information heading

%------------------------------
%   PUBLICATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\noindent\spacedlowsmallcaps{Publications}\vspace{1em}


\begin{thebibliography}{2}

\bibitem{fta}
Bla bla

\bibitem{grey}
Bla bla

\end{thebibliography}

\end{cv}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Helped me a lot! just one question, how can I include the numbering of the publications? because now its gone

Comment: @juniorTeX I revamped my answer; now it should do what you need.

Comment: thats great! thank you very much for all your help and guidance! Highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

If all you wanted to do is change the `natbib` bibliography heading, that is accomplished like so:

```
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\section{Whatever You Prefer}}
```