# Classic thesis CV and \nobibliography

Tags: bibliographies, formatting, cv, classicthesis

I am trying to add my publications in my CV using the `classicthesis` template. Since, I want the citations with no bibliography, I used the package `bibentry` in order to call the `nobibliography` command.

As soon as I try to compile, that is at the first step doing PDFLatex, I am getting the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Lonely \item--perhaps a missing list environment.
```

Out of curiosity, I complied properly to see what sort of output I obtain. That is I did, PDFLatex, BibTeX, PDFLatex, PDFLatex. The pdf is generated without any citations. Any ideas about that?

The code is given below:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Classicthesis-Styled CV
% LaTeX Template
% Version 1.0 (22/2/13)
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% Original author:
% Alessandro Plasmati
%
% License:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass{scrartcl}

\reversemarginpar % Move the margin to the left of the page 

\newcommand{\MarginText}[1]{\marginpar{\raggedleft\itshape\small#1}} % New command defining the margin text style

\usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis} % Use the classicthesis style for the style of the document
\usepackage[LabelsAligned]{currvita} % Use the currvita style for the layout of the document
\usepackage{bibentry}

\renewcommand{\cvheadingfont}{\LARGE\color{Maroon}} % Font color of your name at the top

\usepackage{hyperref} % Required for adding links   and customizing them
\hypersetup{colorlinks, breaklinks, urlcolor=Maroon, linkcolor=Maroon} % Set link colors

\newlength{\datebox}\settowidth{\datebox}{Spring 2011} % Set the width of the date box in each block

\newcommand{\NewEntry}[3]{\noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0 \parbox{\datebox}{\small \textit{#1}}\hspace{1.5em} #2 #3 % Define a command for each new block - change spacing and font sizes here: #1 is the left margin, #2 is the italic date field and #3 is the position/employer/location field
\vspace{0.5em}} % Add some white space after each new entry

\newcommand{\Description}[1]{\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0\noindent\raggedright\footnotesize{#1}\par\normalsize\vspace{1em}} % Define a command for descriptions of each entry - change spacing and font sizes here

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty} % Stop the page count at the bottom of the first page

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   NAME AND CONTACT INFORMATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{cv}{\spacedallcaps{John Smith}}\vspace{1.5em} % Your name

\noindent\spacedlowsmallcaps{Personal Information}\vspace{0.5em} % Personal information heading

\NewEntry{}{\textit{Born in Canada,}}{20 November 1987} % Birthplace and date

\NewEntry{email}{\href{mailto:john@smith.com}{john@smith.com}} % Email address

\NewEntry{website}{\href{http://www.johnsmith.com}{http://www.johnsmith.com}} % Personal website

\NewEntry{phone}{(H) +1 (000) 111 1111\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ (M) +1 (000) 111 1112} % Phone number(s)

\vspace{1em} % Extra white space between the personal information section and goal

\noindent\spacedlowsmallcaps{Goal}\vspace{1em} % Goal heading, could be used for a quotation or short profile instead

\Description{Gain fundamental experience in my area of interest and expertise.}\vspace{2em} % Goal text

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   WORK EXPERIENCE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\noindent\spacedlowsmallcaps{Work Experience}\vspace{1em}

\NewEntry{2012--Present}{1\textsuperscript{st} Year Analyst, \textsc{Lehman Brothers}}

\Description{\MarginText{Lehman Brothers}Developed spreadsheets for risk analysis on exotic derivatives on a wide array of commodities (ags, oils, precious and base metals), managed blotter and secondary trades on structured notes, liaised with Middle Office, Sales and Structuring for bookkeeping. \\ Reference: John \textsc{McDonald}\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ +1 (000) 111 1111\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ \href{mailto:john@lehman.com}{john@lehman.com}}

%------------------------------------------------

\NewEntry{2010--2011}{Summer Intern, \textsc{Initech Inc}  --- Chicago}

\Description{\MarginText{Initech Inc}Rated "truly distinctive" for Analytical Skills and Teamwork. \\ Reference: Bill \textsc{Lumbergh}\ \ +1 (000) 111 1111\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ \href{mailto:bill@initech.com}{bill@initech.com}}

%------------------------------------------------

\NewEntry{Jan-Mar 2011}{Computer Technician, \textsc{Buy More} --- Burbank}

\Description{\MarginText{Buy More}Worked in the Nerd Herd and helped to solve computer problems by asking customers to turn their computers off and on again. \\ Reference: Big \textsc{Mike}\ \ +1 (000) 111 1111\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ \href{mailto:mike@buymore.com}{mike@buymore.com}}

%------------------------------------------------

\vspace{1em} % Extra space between major sections

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   EDUCATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\spacedlowsmallcaps{Education}\vspace{1em}

\NewEntry{2011-2012}{The University of California, Berkeley}

\Description{\MarginText{Masters of Commerce}GPA: 8.0\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ \textit{First Class Honours}\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ School: Business and Administration\newline 
Thesis: \textit{Money Is The Root Of All Evil -- Or Is It?}\newline
Description: This thesis explored the idea that money has been the cause of untold anguish and suffering in the world. I found that it has, in fact, not.\newline
Advisors: Prof.~James \textsc{Smith} \& Assoc. Prof.~Jane \textsc{Smith}}

%------------------------------------------------

\NewEntry{2007-2010}{The University of California, Berkeley}

\Description{\MarginText{Bachelor of Business Studies}GPA: 7.5\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ \textit{Commerce Specialization}\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ School: Business and Administration\newline
Description: This degree focussed heavily on important things such as personnel management and mundane paperwork.}

%------------------------------------------------

\vspace{1em} % Extra space between major sections

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PUBLICATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\spacedlowsmallcaps{Publications}\vspace{1em}

\nocite{*}
\nobibliography{publications}
\bibliographystyle{utphys}

\end{cv}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What is your goal exactly? It looks like you want a list of your publications, this you can do with a combination of `\nocite{*}` and regular `\bibliography{}`, maybe in combination with https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132646/how-to-remove-the-references-title or similar if you don't want the section heading there. Instead, `\nobibliography` (as the name suggests) does not produce a bibliography at all, it just allows you to use `\cite` and `\bibentry` commands in the text.

Comment: @Marijn yes, the goal was precisely that. To have a list of publications without the heading. I managed to solve it using this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/293932/change-remove-predefined-title-from-bibliography-section/294116#294116

Comment: Good that it is solved, I'll vote to close the question here with a 'does this answer your question' comment.